# What is this spurious `Catalina` partition/volume, and can I safely delete it?

Tags: catalina, partition, ventura

I was running Ventura.

I had a second APFS partition. I've just installed macOS (Ventura) onto it & I've booted into the new Ventura.

Now I'm cleaning up.

After a fresh reboot, I see this `Catalina` item in Finder:

[image]

I have no idea what it's doing there. And it appears to be empty: If I right-click -> `Eject Catalina`, I get these 3 dialogs:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I'm hitting `Cancel` each time, as I don't want to risk destabilizing my OS if I don't know what I'm doing.

And now the `Catalina` is vanished from Finder's `locations`.

But rebooting the box, it reappears!

Examining from the terminal:

```
> ll /Volumes/
total 0
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel     1B  2 Dec 21:09 case-insensitive@ -> /
drwxr-xr-x  21 root  wheel   672B 28 Oct 09:43 πTB/
drwxr-xr-x@ 28 root  wheel   896B 29 Sep  2019 πTB - Data/
drwxrwxr-x@  6 root  admin   192B 20 Aug  2019 Catalina/

> ll /Volumes/Catalina/
total 8
-rw-r--r--@  1 pi    admin   6.0K  8 Oct  2019 .DS_Store
d-wx--x--t   7 root  wheel   224B 20 Aug  2019 .Trashes/
drwx------   5 root  admin   160B 20 Aug  2019 .Spotlight-V100/
drwx------  21 root  admin   672B 20 Aug  2019 .fseventsd/
```

What is this rogue `Catalina` volume, and can I safely force-eject these 3 items?

If I `yes` on that force-eject dialog, I get this:

[image]

... which makes me nervous.

Is this related to the fact that I've now got 2 macOS partitions?

Or maybe Catalina was the first OS installed on this MBP? (It's a 2018 MBP, and Catalina was 2019, so that sounds unlikely...).

EDIT:

```
> diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     314.6 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         1.0 TB     disk0s2

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +1.0 TB     disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume πTB - Data              367.3 GB   disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 3.6 GB     disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                2.2 GB     disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      24.6 KB    disk1s4
   5:                APFS Volume Catalina                880.6 KB   disk1s5
   6:                APFS Volume πTB                     8.8 GB     disk1s6
   7:                APFS Volume case-insensitive - Data 13.0 GB    disk1s8
   8:                APFS Volume case-insensitive        8.8 GB     disk1s9
   9:              APFS Snapshot com.apple.os.update-... 8.8 GB     disk1s9s1
```

Comment: Can you add the output from Terminal command `diskutil list`.

Comment: @Gilby done, tx!

Comment: Open the Disk Utility, right click on the `Catalina` volume and then select "Delete APFS Volume...".

Comment: @DavidAnderson But what actually IS it? Why is it even there? Is it a relic from some (auto-)update? Is it being used to disambiguate, now that I have 2 bootable partitions?  How to know if it's safe to delete it?

Comment: Your Catalina volume dates from 3 years ago - do you remember what you did 3 years ago to create it. Safe? Well it is empty - nothing to lose if there is nothing there. Don't delete any other volumes.